# How to control more than one video simultaneously with just one controlbar

Tags: video, video.js

I'm developing a security system and I need to execute more than one video simultaneously on the same browser screen, all of them being controlled by the same controlbar, i.e., each video does not have its own controlbar. Instead of it, there is just one that controls all the videos. So, if I press play all the videos must start playing. If I press stop, all of them must stop and so on... See the picture below.

[image: Screen example.]

I cannot overlay them with FFMPEG because I still may need interact with each one individually (may want to maximize just one camera, for example).

By the way, I'm trying to use Video.js to do this... I've never used it before (neither any kind of video players available on the market! =P), but it seems to be very powerful and flexible...

Beyond all of that, I still need to keep compatibility with the Video.js plugins.

Does anyone have some idea how to do this?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] of what you have tried so far.

Comment: @zer00ne, actually I've not initiated the implementation yet. I was searching for some tools that could help me to do what I need and found Video.js. I saw that it has a lot of plugins with several functionalities that I would need to implement! So I'd like to use them all to avoid too much effort. The only problem that I could antecipate until now is just the one I have already talked about: the necessity to control more than one video simultaneously with just one controlbar. So, just resuming, I'd like to know if it is possible to do this with Video.js and if so, how difficult it is.

Comment: @zer00ne So far I could think in these strategies:
1) Hide the controlbars of each small video player and use one big video player with just the controlbar visible over the other ones. So, everytime someone click in one button of the bigger controlbar, I could call the same click on the other hidden small controlbars. I don't know if I will have some synchronism issue with this strategy.
2) Customize Video.js' source code itself to treat this behave.

Probably both cases could cause some compatibility problems with the plugins. Do you see another way to do this?

Comment: You are developing a security system, so you must determine the source that you get from these 4 video devices. Are these sources from webcams  ? Are the video feed from a third party service? If you have 4 real video security cameras, is a webpage really a practical solution?

Comment: If it is a practical option for you security system to run on a website, I suggest you research HLS for live streaming on HTTP. BTW, this site deals with broken code not general concepts and topics. Ask your question here: http://video.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @zer00ne A brief system description: we have a lot of buses with some cams recording inside of them. These videos will be transferred to a server and one day after they will be watched by some people whose mission is identify some problems that may be occurred, like accidents, robberies, fights inside the vehicles, etc. To be web is a requisite and as the videos will be watched just one day after, live streaming is not necessary.

Comment: BTW, thanks for the tip! I will try to get an answer there!

Comment: In that case Video.js is fine. You have the freedom to develop anyway you wish: 1. You can develop for one browser and not worry about incompatibilities with the rest of the browsers. 2. UX can be minimal which allows you to concentrate on functionality. 3. You don't have to worry about mobile, so you can actually consider the use of flash if you want. I envy you, sir.